# How to get text off a webpage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I want to get text off of a webpage in C#.
I don't want to get the HTML, I want the real text off of the webpage. Like if I type "`<b>cake</b>`", I want the cake, not the tags.

Comment: Check into an HTML parser, such as HTML Agility Pack - and then recursively loop through the DOM and extract the text from each element.

Comment: Have a look at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the HTML Agility Pack library.

That's very fine library for parse HTML, for your requirement use this code:

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("Yor Path(local,web)"); 
    var result=doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//text()");//return HtmlCollectionNode
    foreach(var node in result)
    {
        string AchivedText=node.InnerText;//Your desire text
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can strip tags using regular expressions such as this one<sup>2</sup> (a simple example):

```
// You can import System.Text.RegularExpressions for convenience, of course.
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex tag = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\<.+?\>");
myHTML = tag.Replace(myHTML, String.Empty);
```

But if you need to retrieve large volumes of well-structured data, then you might be better off using an HTML library<sup>1</sup>. (If the webpage is XHTML, all the better - use the `System.Xml` classes.)

<sup>1</sup> Like http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/, for example.
  <sup>2</sup> This might have unintended side-effects if you're trying to get data out of JavaScript, or if the data is inside an element's attribute and includes angle brackets. You'll also need to accept escape sequences like `&amp;`.

Comment: I don't think RegEx would work very well.  You can have angle brackets in HTML that are not part of tags, and they could also appear in CSS, Javascript string constants, etc.  Really the only way to do this is with an HTML parser.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: That's why I was saying a) "a simple example" and b) "large volumes." If the OP only needs a tiny little bit, there's no need to include a full-fledged parser in the project for that one thing. Besides, JavaScript isn't often included in parsing of data, CSS definitely not...

Comment: Yea I figured that's what you meant - I just wanted to point it out more explicitly.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Okay. I'll include a note about that, too.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. **If** your application downloads the webpage using a WebBrowser component, then that component will do the parsing for you automatically in the background (just like Internet Explorer). Just walk the DOM tree and extract the text you want. You will find [HtmlElement.InnerText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext.aspx) especially useful :)